Customize strip invoice pdf

In stripe with prorated charges, invoice show their calculations with negative values. I want to customize those prorated values into one line as accumulated values instead of having multiple line. will it be possible?
can I update invoiceItems to achieve this?

I do no think it's possible to customize that. However, as a work around, you could use the upcoming invoices API, https://docs.stripe.com/api/invoices/upcoming to look the amount and then disabled prorations: https://docs.stripe.com/billing/subscriptions/prorations#disable-prorations. Then, pass in a coupon for instance: https://docs.stripe.com/api/coupons. I would recommend leaving as is so it is clearer to your customers on how each line item is calculated.
